# How can i do certain things in JAXB such as ignore the order of xml elements?

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, annotations

More specific Questions:
How do I overcome the following limitations in JAXB (if possible):

1) validation of an xml file requires creating a schema file somewhere on the HD.  I should not have to create a new file to validate the xml.  I did find a post about this on stack overflow using some streams, but was wondering if there is any other way.

2) how can I specify xml elements out of order in my file and still have it be loaded.
for example i would like both of the following to load correctly:

```
<xml>
 <defaults .../>
 <people>
 ...
 </people>
</xml>

<xml>
 <people>
 ...
 </people>
 <defaults .../>
</xml>
```

code used to unmarshall:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyConfig.class);

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

context.generateSchema(new MySchemaOutputResolver(schemaF));

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaF);
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
MyConfig loaded = (MyConfig)unmarshaller.unmarshal(settingsU);

   private static class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

      public MySchemaOutputResolver(File schemaFile) {
         this.schemaFile = schemaFile;
      }

      @Override
      public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
         return new StreamResult(schemaFile);
      }

      private File schemaFile;
   }
```

Also the same goes for properties.  Ie specifying properties out of order should work also.  I haven't tested the properties, but the above definitely fails to load.  JAXB enforces order on the elements.  Which should be optional in the above exmaple.

3) allow properties and elements to be optional.  If not specified, the file should still load and just not set the missing properties (ie use the default values initialized in the class).  Currently this does not work either.  If i don't put a property even when required=false, it just fails to load the entire file.

Comment: If you don't create a schema for the xml what are you going to validate it against?

Comment: DTD's allow elements in any order XSD's should not any technology that depends on using XSD's you should assume that out of order elements will not behave. I think I mananged to create an XSD once that let me define elements in near random order. I do not recommend doing that and i imagine it would have broken a few xml decoders.

Comment: I'm validating against the annotations specified.  Besides to get the schema is's only line 3 lines of code and it's auto generated from the annotations.  If JAXB can do that at runtime, why do I have to create the schema file on my hard drive just to validate it.  At worst it should be able to create it in memory without me having to bend over backwards to trick it.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for 1**

You could use Bean Validation (JSR 303) annotations to specify validation rules instead of an XML schema.

**Answer for 2 & 3**

By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do not require that elements be in schema order or that required elements be present in order to unmarshal XML into object form.  If you have a `Schema` set you can set a `ValidationEventHandler` to ignore errors.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Hmm, I will have to look into this, but the default implementation does force the order of elements.  Even after I removed the order annotation from the class.  Thanks for your answer I will give it a go when I get a chance.

Comment: Can you post sample code that demonstrates your issue?  What environment are you running in?

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7 JDK 1.7.  I have already included the sample xml, aside from that I use the normal methods to unmarshall my class.  I have updated the question with this code.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-tested and it looks like it only fails to load when I do validation.  So validation (even with a schema file) enforces order of elements which is very useless validation.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @Coder - What aspects do you want to validate against?  The Bean Validation (JSR-303) annotations may make more sense for your use case.